# Android FB SDK login - opens external browser though the FB app is installed

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

My Android app integrates FB SDK login. I am calling

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logIn
```

On one device even if the FB app is installed, the login flow from my app does not open FB app but instead it fires an external browser with login. If I enter credentials there, there is an error saying “Logging in to Facebook from an embedded browser is disabled”
What may be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Facebook app's settings on that device, specifically, the app's **Log in with Facebook** setting may be set to **Disabled** or **Enabled (web only)**. When this setting is disabled, the Facebook app will not handle login requests from other apps, and the request will be sent to the web browser instead.

You can check and change this setting by following these steps:

1- Open the Facebook app on the device

2- Tap on the three horizontal lines in the top right corner of the screen to open the menu

3- Scroll down to the "Settings & Privacy" section and tap on "Settings"

4- Scroll down to the "Media and Contacts" section and tap on "Apps and    Websites"

5- Under "Log in with Facebook", ensure the toggle is enabled.

Another reason that this may be happening is that the app is using an older version of the Facebook SDK. Make sure that you are using the latest version of the Facebook SDK. This version of the SDK will allow you to specify the behavior of the login flow, whether it should open in the Facebook app or in the browser.

Comment: I fear they changed the settings. I can no longer find this settings path.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is on Android 11+ you require a query package reference in your AndroidManifest.xml. Posting in case this is still relevant to anyone.

```
<queries>
        <!-- Enable Facebook Express Login (via Facebook application - query package reference required for Android 11+ otherwise login will be via browser) -->
        <package android:name="com.facebook.katana" />
</queries>
```

More details:

https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring#package-name
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android#expresslogin